# Red and violet bicycle roads

Tags: openstreetmap

What means red and violet roads in https://www.openstreetmap.org Bicycle Layout:

What other colors are available?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

red roads are bicycle highways (cyklomagistrála) while violet ones are unclassified unstable roads. if you zoom in you can use Query features

[image]